# Monocular camera calibration

Tags: ros, calibration, camera1394, camera, monocular-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have followed the monocular calibration tutorial and have calibrated my Firefly_mv (which uses the DC1394 drivers)image. The calibrations seems to be successful since the /camera/camera_info is publishing the correct information:

```
header: 
seq: 152254
stamp: 
secs: 8
nsecs: 21200000
frame_id: /camera
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: plumb_bob
D: [-0.4055357733215121, 0.2322957248510526, -0.000988042635329932,                   0.00818916859481644, 0.0]
K: [701.8606085716559, 0.0, 317.3954985453047, 0.0, 704.0761053327817,      233.51394559637478, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [639.8907470703125, 0.0, 321.50737796160684, 0.0, 0.0, 668.643798828125, 232.067902760391, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
x_offset: 0
y_offset: 0
height: 0
width: 0
do_rectify: False
---
```

However, when I type rostopic echo /image_rect , nothing seems to be published. Where can I find the rectified/calibrated image?

edit:
$ rostopic list:

```
/camera/camera_info
/camera/image_color
/camera/image_color/compressed
/camera/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_color/theora
/camera/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw
/camera/image_raw/compressed
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/image_raw/theora
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera1394_nodelet/parameter_descriptions
/camera1394_nodelet/parameter_updates
/camera_nodelet_manager/bond
/diagnostics
/image_mono
/image_mono/compressed
/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_mono/compressedDepth
/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_mono/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_mono/theora
/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/image_proc_debayer/parameter_descriptions
/image_proc_debayer/parameter_updates
/image_proc_rectify_color/parameter_descriptions
/image_proc_rectify_color/parameter_updates
/image_proc_rectify_mono/parameter_descriptions
/image_proc_rectify_mono/parameter_updates
/image_rect
/image_rect/compressed
/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_rect/compressedDepth
/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_rect/theora
/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/image_rect_color
/image_rect_color/compressed
/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/image_rect_color/theora
/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions  
/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/out
/out/compressed
/out/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/out/compressed/parameter_updates
/out/compressedDepth
/out/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/out/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/out/theora
/out/theora/parameter_descriptions
/out/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Thanks,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52860/monocular-camera-calibration/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running the **image_proc** node? See for http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc details, but mainly, you have to run something like:

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=camera rosrun image_proc image_proc image_raw:=/camera/image
```

and to test

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_rect_color
```

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
Thanks for your reply, I am running the image_proc node and able to view my colored images. I do not have camera/image_rect_color though. I edited the question above to include the output from the rostopic list command.

**Comment by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) on 2013-01-20**:
I agree with Thomas that it is very strange that the rectified topics are published in the global namespace while the camera has its own namespace, i.e. /camera. Could you specify how do you run the image_proc node? rxgraph could help to see if the node is properly subscribed to the right topics.

**Comment by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) on 2013-01-20**:
I agree with Thomas that it is very strange that the rectified topics are published in the global namespace while the camera has its own namespace, i.e. /camera.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
I forgot to do the remapping from image_rect to camera/image_rect in my launch file. I think this should solve the problem. I will try it later and update you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is unlikely that your full qualified topic name is `/image_rect`, it is probable that it is `/camera/image_rect`. Check using `rostopic list` or `rosnode list` / `rosnode info` (or `rxgraph` if you prefer a GUI) which topics are published by your rectification node.

You can also then check if raw data are passing by this topic using `rostopic echo -n 1 --noarr /your/rectified/image/topic` which will display the rectified image header for one image. If this does not display anything it means that either the node crashed, does not publish data or you have some network issues.

Also take a look at the logging information both in the terminal you launched your node and using `rxconsole` and search for error messages.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
Thanks alot for your fast reply,I have edited the question and included the output from the rostopic list command. There is no camera/image_rect

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-20**:
I have just realized that I forgot to do the remapping from image_rect to camera/image_rect from in my launch file. I will try this later and let update you.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-21**:
I added the remapping in the launch file in the image_proc node from image_rect to camera/image_rect but it didn't work, I then tried remapping image_rect_color to camera/image_rect_color and it seems to be working, when I type rostopic echo -n 1 --noarr /camera/image_rect_color  I get:

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-21**:
header:
seq: 3298
stamp:
secs: 33
nsecs: 267680000
frame_id: /camera
height: 960
width: 1280
encoding: mono8
is_bigendian: 0
step: 1280

I am not sure why camera/image_rect does not publish anything but camera/image_rect_color seems to be working fine. Is this ok?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-01-21**:
Normally you don't have to remap the rectification node, just push it into the right namespace using the ROS_NAMESPACE env. variable. See Jordi Pages answer below. You should be able to display this image using image_view for instance now. Is your problem solved?

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-21**:
Yes that worked! the problem is solved, Thank you very much for your help.